# "Connection: Close" in WCF (Windows Store Apps)

Tags: wcf, windows-8

I have written the following program in Windows Store Apps.

```
CustomBinding b = new CustomBinding() ;
TextMessageEncodingBindingElement t = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
HttpTransportBindingElement h = new HttpTransportBindingElement();          
b.Elements.Add(t);
b.Elements.Add(h);

MyService client = new MyService(b, new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8080/"));

var request = ...;
var response = client.Service000(request);
```

I want to set `Connection: Close` in the HTTP header.
But following code occurs error in Windows Store Apps.

```
h.KeepAliveEnabled = false;
```

I tried to add a custom HTTP header in the Message Inspector, but it doesn't work either.
Is there any way to set `Connection: Close` in the HTTP header?